# Unable to autowire service in extended java class, throwing NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to `Autowire` service inside java class which is extended from `TimerTask`. This Returning `null` value while trying to return service in java class. This is the class in which I'm trying to `Autowire` service:

```
@Component
public class Task extends TimerTask

{
    @Autowired
    FileDetailsService fileDetailsService;

    int count = 1;

    @Override
    public void run()
    {   
        fileDetailsService.updateProcessingStatus(fileAudit);
}
```

**Configuration classes:** There is no web.xml.....I have configured in java using spring 4

//DataConfig.java

```
 @Configuration
    @MapperScan("com.fileC.mapper")
    public class DataConfig {
        @Bean
        public DataSource dataSource() {
            SimpleDriverDataSource dataSource = new SimpleDriverDataSource();
            dataSource.setDriverClass(oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.class);
            dataSource.setUsername("username");
            dataSource.setUrl("jdbc***thin**sample **url");
            dataSource.setPassword("****");
            return dataSource;
        }

        @Bean
        public DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager() {
            return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource());
        }

        @Bean
        public SqlSessionFactoryBean sqlSessionFactory() throws Exception {
            SqlSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
            sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
            sessionFactory.setTypeAliasesPackage("com.fileC.model");
            return sessionFactory;
        }
```

//ApplConfig.java

```
 @Configuration
    @ComponentScan(basePackages="com.filec")
    public class ApplConfig {
        @Bean
        public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver(){
            CommonsMultipartResolver commonsMultipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
            commonsMultipartResolver.setDefaultEncoding("utf-8");
            commonsMultipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(50000000);
            return commonsMultipartResolver;
        }
    }
```

I'm using Spring4, java1.8, ibatis, SQL database.

Here is the service class,

```
@Service("fileDetailsService")
@Transactional
public class FileDetailsServiceImpl implements FileDetailsService{
    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FileDetailsServiceImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    FileDetailsMapper fileDetailsMapper;

    @Override
    public void insertFileInfo(Details details){
        fileDetailsMapper.insertDetails(details);
    }
```

Here is the exception details,

fileAuditMapper>>>>null
Exception in thread "Timer-9" java.lang.NullPointerException at com.filecompare.service.Task.run(Task.java:117)
at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)

Please, let me know if I need to add something in config.

Comment: How are you creating the Bean of `FileDetailsService`? Could you add the code of `FileDetailsService` to the question?

Comment: Please use the edit link under your original post to add the details to the question. It's unreadable in the comment without proper formatting. Also, please post how you're creating the `Task` bean.

Comment: Post the complete stack trace of the exception, and post the code where you get e reference to the Task. My guess is that you're using new Task() somewhere.

Comment: Change the class to use constructor injection instead of field injection, and the problem will probably become immediately apparent.